# How does one restrict number of allowed types in Java generic type

Tags: java, generics

Say, i have a generic type as below

```
public class GenericType<T> {
   private T someVar;

   public void setVar(T var) { this.someVar = var; }

   //Rest of the code
}
```

I want to allow it to take only specific types(String/Integer/Double). I know about bounded wildcards but they don't help me here. In setVar(), I can check the `instanceof` and throw an Exception if type is not Integer/String etc. Is this the best way to do it?

I have the same problem when doing operations on this type. Depending on the type, I want to do different operations. Inheritance and bounded wildcards seem like the way to go in general for this kind of problem but these are primitive wrappers.

Comment: Sorry I did not see the String type

Comment: Yeah dude you are stuck with an ugly solution there... There's no straight pretty solution for your problem since the types are unrelated by inheritance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Inheritance:

**Parent.java**

```
public abstract class Parent<T> {
    public abstract void display(T t);
}
```

**ChildString.java**

```
public class ChildString extends Parent<String> {

    @Override
    public void display(String t) {
        // Do something here...
    }

}
```

**ChildInteger.java**

```
public class ChildInteger extends Parent<Integer> {

    @Override
    public void display(Integer t) {
        // Do something here...
    }

}
```

**ChildDouble.java**

```
public class ChildDouble extends Parent<Double> {

    @Override
    public void display(Double t) {
        // Do something here...
    }

}
```

And access the class child rather than you directly access the parent class.

## **Update**

Here another example:

**GenericType.java**

```
public class GenericType {

    public void display(Object t) {
        String msg;
        if(t instanceof String) {
            msg = "String";
        } else if (t instanceof Integer) {
            msg = "Integer";
        } else if (t instanceof Double) {
            msg = "Double";
        } else {
            msg = "Another Object";
        }

        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

**SpecificGeneric.java**

```
public class SpecificGeneric {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericType basicType = new GenericType();

        basicType.display(new String());
        basicType.display(new Integer(1));
        basicType.display(new Double(0.1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Valid answer but doesn't it look like too much trouble to go to just to achieve the desired effect? I mean you need a child class for every type then..

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I just give example based on what questioner need. Let me give another example without using Inheritance :-)

Comment: Don't you think that use of generics is unnecessary here? I mean not in your answer in this whole scenario??

Comment: Nah I mean for this whole problem the answer seem to be removing the generics and checking the passed parameter and if its of wrong type just throw an InvalidInput exception or something.. Good work on the answer though..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (more than extends something, but in your case you want few unrelated types, so it does not help).

What you can, is check instance passed to method (you already know it). If you want one instace of generic class for eg. String another for Integers, but don't allow eg. Point2D, you can make constructor with parameter Class clazz and check when constructing whether its allowed.
If you are more paranoid, you can store that clazz and in all function compare whether parameter is actualy that class.

This way, you can still create MyClass, but cannot create instance with this type. (But you can cast it, co its not fool proof)

Answer (score 0):

Inferring the desired type say `GenericType<Double>` and using `instanceof` when neccesary is the quickest and easy option. Alternatively overload `setVar(..)` to accept the restricted types in your Generic class.

```
  public static class GenericType<T>
  {
    private T someVar;
    public void setVar(String var)
    {
      this.someVar = (T) var;
    }

    public void setVar(Integer var)
    {
      this.someVar = (T) var;
    }

    public void setVar(Double var)
    {
      this.someVar = (T) var;
    }
  }
```